# Access SQL JOIN Expression Not Supported

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know there are a bunch of questions on here dealing of unsupported join expressions, I just can't find one that refers to my situation.

My query looks like this :

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.Year, T3.Force, T4.Group AS myGroup
FROM ((AllQuestions AS T1 
INNER JOIN Years AS T2 ON T1.ID_Year = T2.ID) 
INNER JOIN Forces AS T3 ON T1.Questions_Force = T3.ID)
INNER JOIN Groups AS T4 ON  T4.ID = " & (Me.Texte423) & "
ORDER BY Categories, T1.Questions;
```

As you can see on line refering to T4, I'm trying to match the ID in table Groups to match a value from a textbox in a report (it might be important to mention).

The error i'm getting looks like : JOIN expression not supported.  "looks" because i'm using a french version of Access, so it's a basic translation...

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: What error message are you getting? That always helps us.

Comment: MS  Access doesn't allow use constants in join conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to CROSS JOIN the table `Groups` and then place `T4.ID` in the `WHERE`clause of your query but this doesn't resolve the relationship that may exist between `T4.ID` and the other `ID` columns that are being used to join the other tables:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.Year, T3.Force, T4.Group AS myGroup
FROM ((AllQuestions AS T1 
INNER JOIN Years AS T2 ON T1.ID_Year = T2.ID) 
INNER JOIN Forces AS T3 ON T1.Questions_Force = T3.ID)
CROSS JOIN Groups AS T4 
WHERE T4.ID = " & (Me.Texte423) & "
ORDER BY Categories, T1.Questions;
```

If there is a relationship between Groups and AllQuestions on ID then you need to modify your query along these lines:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.Year, T3.Force, T4.Group AS myGroup
FROM ((AllQuestions AS T1 
INNER JOIN Years AS T2 ON T1.ID_Year = T2.ID) 
INNER JOIN Forces AS T3 ON T1.Questions_Force = T3.ID)
INNER JOIN Groups AS T4 ON T1.{Group ID Relation} = T4.ID
WHERE T4.ID = " & (Me.Texte423) & "
ORDER BY Categories, T1.Questions;
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I really never had to use cross joins but it could make sense...  I tried the first solution since I don't want to use the relation between Groups and AllQuestions, but I get this error when executing : syntax error in the where clause, and the word CROSS is highlighted...

Comment: This is the solution, only Access doesn't have the `CROSS JOIN` keyword. Instead of it, simply use a comma `,` in the FROM list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. But you can modify the SQL of the query. Set it to:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.Year, T3.Force, T4.Group AS myGroup
FROM ((AllQuestions AS T1 
INNER JOIN Years AS T2 ON T1.ID_Year = T2.ID) 
INNER JOIN Forces AS T3 ON T1.Questions_Force = T3.ID)
INNER JOIN Groups AS T4 ON  T4.ID = {0}
ORDER BY Categories, T1.Questions;
```

Then set/modify the SQL when you need it:

```
MyQdy.SQL = Replace(SQL, "{0}", Me!Texte423.Value)
```

Comment: I tried that and I get an error saying : The format of this GUID is incorrect: "T4.ID = {0 ".

Comment: You need, of course, to run the replace before running the SQL.